# Is this how stock trading works?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, stock-valuation

This is a very basic question about the Stock Exchange, and I was looking for some concrete answers with a general understanding of how it works.

When a Stock Exchange is open for business in a country showing Public Limited Companies which are floating on said Stock Exchange, I assume that people within that country get 'signals' as to whether the current share price is going up, or down, before someone from another country, around a millisecond faster? Thus, if one could quickly stop time with a magic watch, walk across the Earth to another country, and quickly lock in a trade they would make the correct decision resulting in profit?

I will note, however, that the United States of America seems to use some form of lag, on purpose, so that they get up to date information which [Tom Scott reports on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8BcCLLX4N4).

Why do I ask? Because I have developed a physics technique to transfer a flag (which could represent a price going up or down) from a country, to another country, faster than anything currently available on the market. I believe I could pay off my student loan with this if I can hook up my physics device to a computer, and have a receiver in another country that inputs the trade.

**Edit 1:** to clarify I am happy to trade anything, for example foreign currency exchange (FOREX), so long as me knowing what a company within a country does quicker than everyone else gives me a competitive advantage.

**Edit 2:** I assume if I am trading on the London Stock Exchange, but knew something about the New York Stock Exchange before the London one I would have an advantage? I know nothing so please correct me.

Comment: This question seems offtopic as it is not much related to "personal financing" area.

Comment: Any idea where I could ask how this works?

Comment: First, I'm guessing that PLC is an acronym for Public Limited Company here.  It would be helpful to specify that.  Second, the YouTube video you link to talks about one specific (and very small) stock exchange that intentionally adds a delay in comparison to all the big exchanges where large companies invest millions to get their servers as close as possible to the exchange to minimize delays (as discussed at the beginning of that very video).

Comment: This is so technical, so I have no clue about. I dont think that anyone uses high-frequency trading for personal financing, I can imagine only that this is what big and rich companies can afford. I wish you best of luck, but no idea even where to redirect your question.

Comment: If you have developed the ability to send information faster than the speed of light, yes that would be advantageous.  I would hope that you'd be publishing papers on the fundamental advance you've made in physics and doing far more than paying off your student loans.

Comment: @JustinCave Updated. Very true, sorry I only included that link to show that I might avoid America or places that purposes put a delay.

Comment: @tym32167 I might not necessarily do "high frequency trading" just anything where me knowing something from another country, being rapidly transferred as a signal elsewhere, can help me profit.

Comment: @JustinCave Not speed of light, but certainly faster, sadly it's not something that can be published so it's a useless discovery unless I find a purpose for it. It's only good for tiny amounts of information, so it's not about to be 6G or something haha.

Comment: @securityauditor - High-frequency traders can already send information at essentially the speed of light from one point to another.  So if you're trying to send information about the current price of a security on the New York stock exchange to a trader on the London Stock Exchange, you'd need to beat the speed of light.  Without advances in fundamental physics, that would likely require the ability to build a device based on stable quantum entanglement which would be a massive, massive advance.

Comment: "How could I profit from a faster way of sending information" might find a better audience at https://quant.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @JustinCave Are there perhaps smaller exchanges? For example: if I send information from the New York Stock Exchange to a smaller Stock Exchange elsewhere, even if it's not faster based your scenario above, would I be able to profit this way?

Comment: @securityauditor - Any exchanges of any size are almost certainly going to have fiber links which are essentially transmitting at the speed of light.  Barring that, you can always send signals at essentially the speed of light off a satellite from one point to another.  You have to go a bit further since you're going up to space, of course, but you're still getting pretty close to the speed of light minus processing time on both ends.

Comment: If you can find two exchanges that trade the same thing at the same time and aren't connected by fiber and your device can send information faster than you can bounce it off a satellite, then it would potentially be worth something to a high-frequency trading firm that could use it to make money on arbitrage.  That strikes me as rather unlikely but, hey, advances do happen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not relevant to personal finance.

Comment: What if I traded on a smaller broker, that did not get this up to date information as quickly as one of the bigger exchanges?

Answer (score 3):

> Because I have developed a physics technique to transfer a flag (which could represent a price going up or down) from a country, to another country, faster than anything currently available on the market.

No, you haven't. Market Information these days travels almost instantaneously and in general a lot faster than trades can actually be executed. Your "new" system would also need to interface with both ends of the Information chain and the Interfaces themselves would most likely be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that you've made a significant advance in communication, the easiest option would be to do arbitrage.  If you identify the same stock, commodity, or currency pair trading on two exchanges at the same time, you could buy on the exchange where the item is cheaper and sell on the exchange where the item is more expensive and make money on the difference.

As a practical matter, however, this is very unlikely.

- It is already possible (and very common) for high-frequency traders to send this sort of information around the world at essentially the speed of light.  Most of the time, the information is going to go via terrestrial fiber optic cable but worst case it'll bounce off a satellite.  Either of those are essentially light speed communication (though the distance for something involving a satellite will obviously be greater than the point-to-point distance).

  If we assume you're competing with fiber, [you'd need to beat
  ~0.7c](https://www.wired.com/2013/03/internet-at-the-speed-of-light/) (possibly faster, this article is several years old).  If
  we assume you're going up and down to a satellite in low earth orbit,
  that adds at most 4,000 km which light would travel in roughly 13
  milliseconds.

  If your device can beat a direct fiber connection, there is the potential to profit on arbitrage.  Otherwise, your device would need to be able to transmit
  information faster than the satellite could between two exchanges
  that traded the same item and weren't connected by fiber.  If such an
  exchange & commodity pair exists, it is likely that it would already
  be economically feasible to connect them with fiber to do arbitrage and that somebody would already have laid that fiber
  so you'd need something where direct fiber connection wasn't
  possible.  It's hard for me to think of a physical reason that you
  couldn't do a fiber connection but there are lots of small exchanges
  in the world, maybe there are political reasons that one is
  accessible only via satellite.
- If you were going to exploit microsecond advantages, you'd have to be a high frequency trader.  That's going to involve several million dollars worth of infrastructure to do things like host your servers as close as physically possible to the two exchanges, writing hyper-optimized code to execute your trades, a significant amount of trading capital to be able to make money on tiny price differences, etc.  If you have student loans, I'll safely assume that you aren't already wealthy enough to do this so you'd realistically need to sell the device to an existing high-frequency trading firm.

If you actually have a device that transmits information faster than the best fiber optic cable in the world, that would be a significant achievement that should generate plenty of scientific interest.

Comment: So where does a FOREX platform like Plus500 get the data from? Surely, I could get information quicker than that platform could update their prices...

Comment: @securityauditor - Presumably, they're getting a feed from the exchange.  But getting information faster than a consumer trading platform isn't likely to be beneficial.  You'd need to get the information faster than the high frequency traders that are already doing arbitrage.

Comment: Why not? If I know a price will go up before the commercial trading platform then I can quickly buy...

Comment: @securityauditor - If you are entering a market order, the price on the screen is not necessarily the price you'll get.  Your order will be sent to the exchange and matched with other orders.  The high-frequency traders can place orders much, much faster than you and have much more current data so they'll have long since moved the price up or down to take advantage of the arbitrage opportunity.  You have to beat their orders to the exchange and you're not going to be able to do that using consumer trading software.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically Yes.  Not sure for stocks but for FX.  If you are able to know that the exchange rate goes up/down you might be able to make a $. BUT you are bound by your brokers trade delay, so practically nope.

Comment: What if I traded on a smaller broker, that did not get this up to date information as quickly as one of the bigger exchanges?